# Chronos Proxying Request to same Node

Tags: cron, mesos, mesosphere, apache-zookeeper

I have a three node chronos cluster. When request reach node 1 I see in the log that chronos proxying request to node2_hostname:4400 which is expected.

When I check the chronos logs on node 2, I see entries saying Proxying request to node2_hostanme:4400 (the same node) and job is never scheduled. I don't understand why th log says the request is proxying to the same node. Any leads on this will be much appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is an open issue in chronos. Please refer to the below pull request for more information.

https://github.com/mesos/chronos/pull/497